# How to change the background of the status bar to a gradient without affecting the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager, android-statusbar

I'm trying to make my status bar show a gradient exactly like the background below it, much like in this question: [How to apply gradient to status bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907237/how-to-apply-gradient-to-status-bar-in-android)

However the answer to that question causes the entire layout to extend into the navigation bar, something which I want to avoid.

I can't find a way that doesn't use  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` and have the status bar either be completely transparent or have it show a gradient (the same one as the one below it.

Is there a way I can have the status bar show a gradient, and not affect the navigation bar? Ideally what is seen is the status bar is "invisible", where the power/wifi/etc icons are still visible but the colors seen are the gradient of the layout that is currently active.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve your goal.

Set window background as gradient and status bar color is transparent.

Here is sample code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     Window window = getWindow();
     Drawable background = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_gradient); //bg_gradient is your gradient.
     window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
     window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
     window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this type of task. You have to set first `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag in your activity or fragment as,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

Now, in your XML just set a `view` at top of layout like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/status_bar_view"
        android:background="#000"       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="22dp">
                 //main layout here.
    </RelativeLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

So, the top view takes the place of statusbar in layout and you can set background of view as you want. In above `view`, I just used black color you can also set a gradient as a background.

**EDIT**

But also we have to set `view` dynamically because height of statusbar is different on each device according to screen size. So, statusbar height you calculate as,

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Above method returns the statusbar height for each device. You can set this as a height for `view`. So your view, looks exactly like statusbar in size.

Comment: it works but what if I don't remove the navigationbar ? because with this code , the activity content goes below the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

func setGradientStatusBar() {

```
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:375, height:64)
    let colorTop = UIColor(red: 85/255, green: 66/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 169/255, green: 132/255, blue: 69/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)
    let window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (window?.frame.width)!, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.07)
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    window?.addSubview(view)
}
```